# PostgreSQL PostGIS vs ElasticSearch Spatial search

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, geospatial, postgis

I am working on a search query which needs to do a geospatial filter (i.e. filter all elements outside of a certain radius). We have both PostgreSQL and ElasticSearch as part of our infrastructure and I am evaluating which of the two to use.

I'm not asking for "which is better", but an objective pros & cons list would be helpful, in terms of ease of implementation, performance, scalability, etc.

Comment: I have been using Postgres/Postgis for years and am about to start testing some geocoding and fuzzy address matching with Lucene and Solr (which I have never used, but have seen a couple of very positive presentions on). I will let you know if I find anything that might be useful to you. What size datasets are you looking at and could you give a little more information on the kind of queries you might be running.

Comment: @JohnBarça That would be great, please let me know if you find out something interesting. I'm interested in 2 types of queries (although very similar in nature): 1) get a set of results which are within a certain proximity in no particular order (i.e. a filter by proximity), and 2) return a set of results sorted by proximity, nearest first.

Answer (score 17):

The postgis scales the same way as postgresql scales. The postgis index will work pretty the same as other relational, you may check it out [here](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html).

If you take a look at the link, it explains that it indexes using some geometrical algorithm which is performed on each insert operation, so it might not be responsive enough in real-time apps.

While elasticsearch have real time indexing, based on Lucene index. Elastic search generally suits better for realtime heavy applications, then Postgresql.

Postgresql has a huge advantage it is simplicity. It is much easier to implement test and maintain such a feature using Postgresql. For example, I prefer creating prototype based on Postgresql quickly, and if it starts perform bad because of big amount of writes, etc. I switch to elasticsearch implementation.